# How do you measure 2 ounces of dry thin spaghetti pasta?

Tags: measurements, spaghetti

I tried the size of a quarter and a juice bottle with a long neck. When I cook half of what I measure as 2 ounces it is enough for me. Two ounces according to the quarter theory makes a mountain of pasta. I am thinking maybe there is a difference between the pasta size? The thin spaghetti has a smaller diameter and maybe a handfull that has the diameter of a quarter is 3 ounces not 2 ounces.

Does anyone know.I didn't want to but I guess I need to buy a scale.

Comment: Just gotta use that eggwhisk very fast.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you make spaghetti, pay attention to the size of the bundle before cooking and then pay attention to whether it makes the desired amount, so that you get used to the correct sized bundle for the pasta you are using. As you note, different pasta may have different thickness and length so the size of the bundle might be different for different brands.

Having said that, a scale is a very useful kitchen tool and good compact electronic scales can be obtained very cheaply. I would recommend one in general, not just for measuring pasta portions. Then you can get used to what your preferred mass of dry pasta is and measure more confidently for any pasta shape.

Comment: I think you are right on. I am planning to buy a scale now. Measuring pasta is not a one size fits all unless you have measured it with a scale first and know the amount 2 ounces is for that particular pasta.

Comment: An accurate kitchen scale is useful for **many** things.

Answer (score 7):

If you are willing to spread out a whole box of pasta (so you know how much you are starting with - 16, 12, 8 or whatever number of ounces) you can divide the spread out pasta into, say, 8 (roughly) equal piles from a 16 ounce box (halves, quarters, eighths by dividing in two and repeating.)

But a scale is a very useful thing to have in the kitchen.

Comment: You are creative. I feel stupid not thinking of that.  I bought a very nice 500 gram scale this morning and  as I suspected 2 ounces is a lot of pasta ,double what I have been eating and all the time thinking I was eating a normal serving.. I am using the scale to weigh my beans and bread too. I love it.